# Parsing a fixed-size message using variable length array in C

Tags: c

My C program has to parse a fixed-length message like this:

```
uint8_t message[8] = {80, 75, 73, 71, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

another message could be:

```
uint8_t message[8] = {80, 75, 73, 71, 41, 42, 1, 1};
```

The message contains an ASCII string and 1 shows the end of string. So the actual length of the first message is 4 and the second message is 6.

I use this method to extract the message:

```
1. Counting the message length
2. Initializing a variable length array with this value.
3. Using memcpy to copy the bytes.
```

**Code Snippet**

*In the library file:*

Counting the length:

```
...
#define LENGTH 100
// Global variables in library
uint8_t message[LENGTH];
uint8_t parsed_message[LENGTH];
uint8_t len = 0;
...

for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {
        if (message[i] != 1)
        {
            parsed_message[i] = message[i];
            len++;
        }
        else
        {
            parsed_message[i] = '\0';
            len++;
            break;
        }

    }
```

Getter functions:

```
void get_address(char * addr, int size)
{
    memcpy(addr, message, size);
}


uint8_t get_size(void)
{
    return len;
}
```

*In the main function:*

```
char addr[get_size()];
get_address(addr, get_size());
printf("==== %s ==== ADDRESS\n", addr);
```

[I ommitted size and null checks in snippets]

I use GCC compiler and C99 standard in ARM-Based 32-bit micro-controller.

My question is that is this method safe? Or I should use another approach.

Comment: It looks ok to me. And as far as I can see (unless there's something that's not shown in your code section) you could even probably do the same substitution  _in place_ (that is in `message` array). It would be a oneliner.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I mean the line: char addr[get_size()];

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks. I edited.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Again, it should work. In this case my personal feeling is that a function called `get_size ()` should... get the size instead of just returning a global variable updated somewhere else.

Comment: After all I have to say that it is difficult to provide an answer to this question. Without a specific problem, if this solution seems to work, an answer could be just a set of suggestions to improve the code, which makes probably this suggestion more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than for SO.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Thanks.,

Comment: I can anyway summarize my suggestion here. If you don't need the original message anymore, you can simply update it in place so that will basically be a string (`"PKIG"` in your first example). In this way your `get_size ()` will be `strlen ()` and your `get_address () will be `strcpy ()` . You `message` will **already** contain the address and will be able to be printed _directly_ with no vla. If you still need a vla, remember that the required size will be `strlen (message)+1`, in order to make room for the string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Include a byte that holds the actual count of bytes in the message where you send it to this program, and then make your operations using that count byte.

Comment: I receive the message from back-end. But yes, it's actually  a choice which could be applied in the message source.